# Padronizar mensagens de erro em DataAnnotations nas classes de ViewModels

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net

É possível padronizar as mensagens de erro utilizadas em DataAnnotations, de forma que não seja preciso passar toda vez uma string como:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Este campo é obrigatório.")]
```

Mas que possa utilizar mais ou menos assim:

```
string mensagem = "Este campo é obrigatório.";
[Required(ErrorMessege = mensagem)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Sim, usa um Resource para isso. No meu caso ele se chama MensagemErro.resx:

```
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "CampoObrigatorio", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(MensagemErro))]
```

Basicamente eu falo que eu tenho um recurso do tipo `MensagemErro` com um nome chamado `CampoObrigatorio`.

[image: Imagem de como ficaria o resource]

Nesse meu exemplo eu ainda uso um {0} para concatenar um nome, mas ignore no seu caso.